# database connections keep rising

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

On my website I include a connect file in each page the following code:

```
try {                                                                                 
$DB = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);  

}
catch(PDOException $e) {      
 echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```

Then throughout each page various functions are called, each function looks similar to this:

```
function getAllBenchmarkQuestions($sid){                
global $DB;  
$quizHandle = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM benchmarkquestions
                            WHERE sid = :sid AND active = 0");   
$quizHandle->bindParam(':sid', $sid);
$quizHandle->execute();
$quizHandle->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $quizHandle;
}
```

If I run show status like '%onn%'; I get this:

```
Aborted_connects    9505
Connections 1577837
Max_used_connections    52
Threads_connected   3
```

Even if there are no users other than me on the site, The number of connections seems to be going up every time I refresh the command, about 4 - 5 per second.

I have been running into a lot of problems with maxing out the number of connections and trying to figure out how to resolve the problem. There are a few pages that are called via ajax and I include the connect file. The pages called via ajax are used to insert data based on user interaction, for example:

```
<?php session_start();
include('../includes/startup.php');
$questionId = $_POST['questionId'];
$answer = $_POST['answer'];

insertQuizAnswer($questionId, $userId, $answer, 1);

?>
```

Am I setting this up incorrectly?

Comment: You should close your `$quizhandle` etc connection when you're finished with it, that'll help: `$quizhandle = null;`
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score 0):

In theory, perhaps you can store the connection in a session variable?